# Yii2 session problems for multiple application in single domain

Tags: php, session, cookies, yii2, session-cookies

We configured like `/var/www/app1` and `/var/www/app2` , Both are logging in single session. How can I make this different session.

I tried with following solution from yii2 wiki. But it doesn't workout here.

```
'identityCookie' => [
    'name' => '_backendUser', // unique for backend
    'path'=>'/advanced/backend/web' // correct path for the backend app.
]
```

Please give solution for this issue.

Comment: You might want to post some more information... What do you mean with "logging in single session"? Are these the same applications, the same session-data folder, ... ? People only know what you write here, they can't see your code.

Answer (score 5):

Use a different session [`$name`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#$name-detail) for each application. This can be set in your config as:

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'class' => '\yii\web\Session',
        'name' => 'mycustomname',
```

Comment: Have you set different names? I've tested it on localhost and it is working.

Comment: Yes i have set different name, In my ubuntu linux server not working